# no puedo editar valor de input de mi todo list javascript

Tags: javascript, array, local-storage, indices, index

el boton de editar tarea funciona bien el problema es que al editar el input y dar enter se me agrega una nueva tarea en vez de q se actualize, no entiendo que tengo que hacer para que se renderize, otro problema es que al borrar una tarea se ve en el input el texto q yo tenia en la tarea borrada

```
const render = () => {

 const todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list");
 let todosTemplate = [...new Set(todos1)].map((t, id) => {
   return `<li onclick='editTask(${id}, "${t}")'>${t}<span class="icon1"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span><span class="icon2"><i class="fas fa-edit"> </i></span></li>`;
 });
 todoList.innerHTML =
   todosTemplate.join("") || `<span>You don't have any task here</span>`;

   const actualizaTodos = () => {
   localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos1)); 
    };

  deleteAllBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    todos1 = []; 
    actualizaTodos();
    render(); 
 });

 function editTask(id, name) {
   let editId = id;
   inputBox.value = name;
   actualizaTodos();
   render();
 }

     window.onload = () => {
       render();
       const form = document.getElementById("todo-form");
       form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       const todo = document.getElementById("todo");
       const todoText = todo.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
       todos1.push(todoText);
       actualizaTodos(todos1);
       render();
       todo.value = "";
       addBtn.classList.remove(".active");
   });
 };
```

me cuesta entender el tema del indice en el array (local storage) como se hace para que al editar determinado li se renderize y no se agregue uno nuevo

Comment: No estás actualizando uno solo... estás repintando toda la lista completa de cada vez.

Comment: lo dices por el codigo que esta dentro de la funcion editTask?

Comment: Hola Luciano. En la función que guarda el `todo` te falta chequear si estas editando o es uno nuevo. Esto lo podes lograr agregando una variable "global" que te sirva de bandera, o un `input`, etc.